# Converting the getSelectedItem() from JComboBox to int or any other thing

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

How to convert the getSelectedItem() from JComboBox to int or any other thing? Even converting to string isn't working. Eclipse says " Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to String" or int or whatever. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: If you don't understand why you can't cast an `Object` to a primitive, then you need to spend some time understanding the fundamentals of Java...

Comment: Try `getSelectedItem.toString()`

Answer (score 5):

It works just fine here with objects.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class TestCombo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Integer[] numbers = {1,2,3};
                String[] names = {"Ben", "Jill", "Peter"};
                JComboBox numberCombo = new JComboBox(numbers);
                JComboBox nameCombo = new JComboBox(names);
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,3,3));
                p.add(numberCombo);
                p.add(nameCombo);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);

                Integer chosenNumber = (Integer)numberCombo.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println("Chosen Number: " + chosenNumber);
                String chosenName = (String)nameCombo.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println("Chosen Name: " + chosenName);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Typical output:

```
Chosen Number: 2
Chosen Name: Peter
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I agree strongly with the comment by LBFF.  You need to go back to the basics.

Comment: Your answer worked for me and I would say great work

Answer (score 3):

The answer really depends on what kind of items you placed into the `JComboBox` to begin with. Whatever you put into it (eg. with [`addItem()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#addItem%28java.lang.Object%29) or [`insertItemAt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#insertItemAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int%29)) is what you can get out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast it to `(String)`.

```
String value = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//compiled in netbeans

import java.awt.GridLayout;<br>
import javax.swing.JComboBox;<br>
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;<br>
import javax.swing.JPanel;<br>
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;<br>

class TestCombo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Integer[] numbers = {1,2,3};
                String[] names = {"Ben", "Jill", "Peter"};
                JComboBox numberCombo = new JComboBox(numbers);
                JComboBox nameCombo = new JComboBox(names);
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,3,3));
                p.add(numberCombo);
                p.add(nameCombo);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);

                Integer chosenNumber = (Integer)numberCombo.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println("Chosen Number: " + chosenNumber);
                String chosenName = (String)nameCombo.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println("Chosen Name: " + chosenName);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = comboBox.getSelectedItem(comboBox.getSelectedIndex());
```

No casts are required.